# android studio phone emulator gone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio, but when I first used it I had a nexus phone displayed on the right side of the workspace. Now it is gone.

Right side here is blank:
[image: Right side here is blank]

How it is supposed to be:
[image: How it is supposed to be]

It might be because I am running a newer version, I am doing the Udemy course and the newer version has already made some things confusing. Anyways hope somebody could help.

Comment: Are you try with another device render ? Click into Nexus 4 and choose another device.

Comment: I tried it with every single nexus device, but it did not show up. But when I first got Android studio it would show up. So maybe I hit a setting that hides it or something.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an emulator. That is just the preview that shows you what the layout should look like. You can see it by hitting the "Preview" tab on the right side.

Comment: When I hit the preview tab on the right side, the tab just goes back to the tool bar. I think it would be more neat to have it, so I can easily see what my code does.

Comment: In your picture, on the bottom of the xml editor, there's a button called "Design". When you hit that button, what do you see?

Comment: When I go from text to design, the palette opens in the center of the screen and on the right is a even bigger blank screen